# How can i use/display a file content uploaded to ipage ftp in my weebly site?

Tags: c#, php, ftp

This is the code i'm using to upload a simple text file to my ipage.com ftp:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ScrollLabelTest
{
    class FtpFileUploader
    {
        static string ftpurl = "ftp://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com";
        static string filename = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static string ftpusername = "newsxpressmediacom";
        static string ftppassword = "*****";
        static string value;

        public static void test()
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
                ftpurl + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filename));
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);

                // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
                StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
                byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                sourceStream.Close();
                request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

                response.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                string t = err.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I see the text file: test.txt on my ipage ftp now. But how can i display on my weebly site the content of the text file i just uploaded ? The ftp in ipage.com is my website domain name ftp account.

I just talked to the help support live chat they told me there is no way to do it.

What i want to do is to upload somehow a text file from my hard drive to my site and display the content of the text file on my site each a minute since the text file is getting update every a minute.

This is what they wrote about the ipage ftp:

You can build your site using Web authoring tools, and then use an FTP program to upload the Web pages to your iPage account.

To access your account using an FTP client, you need to connect to ftp.newsxpressmedia.com with your FTP username and password.

And: newsxpressmedia.com is my website domain on weebly.
I can edit drag and drop and design my site on weebly but how can i display the content of a text file every a minute ?

Answer (score 0):

I know not all but some ftp sites have a "change permissions" setting for each file or folder, if it has that setting then you can change permissions to allow anybody to view the file and just put the direct file location